# In Azure DevOps pipelines for .Net Core applications, how can I authenticate against an Azure Artifacts feed without using the .NetCoreCLI task?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dotnet-cli

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline for one of my .Net Core projects.  I would like to encapsulate as much of the build process as possible so I can run builds on my local machine, so I have the steps of restore, compile, test, publish, etc. encapsulated in a build script which I call from my Azure DevOps pipeline.

The [.Net Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) task [automatically handles authentication to Azure Artifacts feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/dotnet-exe?view=azure-devops), which is great when you want to script out your build in your pipeline, but I really want to add a task which only does the authentication part and passes off responsibility for everything else to my build script.  Is there some way to authenticate without doing a restore?

Here's the relevant portion of my pipeline:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'NuGet Authentiation and Restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: 'src/*.sln'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      vstsFeed: '5483129a-4405-40c1-8ccb-a688120b3137'
      includeNuGetOrg: false 

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'Build release distribution'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    inputs:
      command: custom
      verbose: false
      customCommand: 'run build'
```

The `npm run build` step will call `dotnet restore` which succeeds because the packages are already restored, but I'm really just using the DotnetCoreCLI task for it's authentication ability.  I don't really want it to restore.  I mean, it works, but it just feels messy.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to authenticate without doing a restore?

Since you are using the npm feed, you could try to use the `npm authenticate` task to authenticate the azure artifacts feed.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create `.npmrc` file in the same directory as your package.json.

For example:

[image]

Step2: Navigate to `Azure Artifacts -> Connect to feed -> Npm` to get the .npmrc file content.

For example:

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/project/_packaging/456/npm/registry/ 
                        
always-auth=true
```

Step3: Add the [npm authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops) task.

```
- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'npm Authenticate package/.npmrc'
  inputs:
    workingFile: package/.npmrc
  enabled: false
```

This allows subsequent build steps to use the credentials in the .npmrc.

For more detailed information, you could refer to this doc about [npm authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#with-a-task-runner-eg-make-gulp-work).

**Update:**

For Nuget feed, you could use the [NuGet Authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget-authenticate?view=azure-devops) task.

For example:

```
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'NuGet Authenticate'
  inputs:
    nuGetServiceConnections: 'test nuget feed'
```

If you do not set the service connection, it will authenticate the default feed.

If you want to specify the feed, you need to create a nuget service connection.

[image]

Feed URL: `Azure Artifacts -> Connect to feed -> Nuget`

User name and Password: you could use current account or PAT.

Comment: I apologize if my question was unclear, but I'm only using NPM as a build tool.  The feed that needs to be authenticated is a NuGet feed, not an npm feed.

Comment: Hi @DerekGreer. Thanks for your clarification. I have Updated the answer. Please check it.

Comment: Hi @DerekGreer. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.